# Sony VAIO VGN-FZ31S overheating

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, sony-vaio

My laptop Sony VAIO VGN-FZ31S was working quite slow back in June and since I needed a computer I decided to get a PC instead. Now due to work need a laptop again, and tried to make it work rather than spending a lot of money on a new one, specially after buying the PC.

The last time I used it everything was fine, now when I turn it on, it reaches the desktop with no problem, but after some minutes the screen goes black, but it keeps running with the fans and all. It seems that theres no image at all, so may not be a backlight problem. I think its neither dust related since I vacuumed it trying to discard that issue. I've been told that it might be the inner battery, but I'd like to hear some other opinions before messing around.

Edit: So, I tried connecting it to another screen and when one went off, the other one did so as well. Then I tried running with a live CD, that doesn't use the graphic card, and it stays on.
Seems like the graphic card NVIDIA GeForce 8600M GS may have been broken itself at some point after I stopped using it in June.
The fact is that I think maybe I could keep using the laptop to program with it disabled, but now I realized it heats to unbelievable levels, what could I do?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You vacumed your computer?

Comment: How skillled of an electronics technician are you?  There are things you can check and possibly fix if you are skilled and have the right tools.  Otherwise, this appears to be a very old model and it could cost more to get it diagnosed than it might be worth (with no guarantee the problem can be cost-effectively fixed).  For what it would cost to repair it, you could probably find another used or refurbished laptop.  You could then use its hard disk as an additional drive  (for a non-critical purpose since it is probably on borrowed time at this age).

Comment: @Xavierjazz Nope, sorry, used compressed air can.

Comment: @fixer1234 I've a degree in computer science, feel free to suggest the fixes that comes to your mind so I can try em please :)

Comment: First, use a flashlight to confirm the problem isn't the backlight.  It could be heat related.  Use compressed air (as a chiller), to check for an overheated component or bad solder joint (opens with thermal expansion).  Check the integrity of the cable that runs through the lid hinge (signs of breakage from fatigue). Continued in next comment.

Comment: There are many small, delicate connectors between the screen and the system board.  Some are accessible, some require screen disassembly.  Some may be just sockets for a ribbon cable.  Start with the most accessible.  Wiggle the cables a little to check for a loose connection.  Look for signs of dirt or corrosion.  If you can separate the connector without damage, clean both sides and reconnect.  Test after each one so you don't disturb more than is necessary.  If you have a monitor that will connect to an external port, test to see if it loses the signal.

Comment: If there are screen controls (brightness, contrast, etc.), try to see if one is dirty or damaged or worn out.  Check the connections to them.  Check the power saver and screen saver settings to make sure it isn't set to blank the screen after a few minutes.

Comment: I updated the question. The graphic card may be broken, but I think I should fix the overheating problem before trying to do something about the graphic card